# SSIS Data Flow: Join the auxiliar flow to the main flow

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, bids

The 'conditional split task' is like a If/Else behavior of programming language. But I don't want only these split behavior. I want to unite a recent opened flow( little scope ) to the main flow;

Using programming language as a example, what I want is this:

```
//this is the main flow
task1;
task2;
task3;
If( condition )
{
   //Now I have the auxiliar flow possibility
   taskAuxiliar1;
   taskAuxiliar2;
   taskAuxiliar3;
   taskAuxiliar4;
}
//Now a single main flow again** ( I want do this )
task4;
task5;
```

What I can do for resolve this without lose performance inside the data flow?? I don't know if merge/join tasks are good for that, because I read these tasks are bad for performance. I want a auxiliar flow with a little scope to do few things, and after that unite again to the main flow.

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: pseudo code doesn't reflect data flow very well. To get two datasets together you either use a join or a lookup or a union. Depends on what you want to do

Comment: Nick, thank you for your comment. In a case where in task I get the information from a SQL table before 'conditional split', and in the split I do some little manipulations in the data fields, always respecting the original structure. With your options, what is the best to unite this auxiliar flow in the main flow after the little manipulations without lose performance?

Comment: All SSIS transformations lose performance. If all of the data is on the SQL Server then the most performant method is almost always using a stored procedure. SSIS slows things down. The only way to stick two conditional splits together in SSIS is to use a UNION transformation http://www.excoded.com/learn/ssis/ssis_unionall.php

Comment: However, if you union after you split, it would appear there was no reason to split it in the first place.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Multicast with one path to continue to task4 and another path to "Conditional Split" the If test