# SSIS Data Flow: duplicated rule problem after lookup

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, bids

I have a data flow that I need to get a column value from 'SQL tableA' and do a lookup task in 'SQL tableB' using this column value. If the lookup found a connection between the two tables, I need to get the value of another column from 'SQL tableA' and put this value in 'SQL tableC'( the table that will be persisted ). If lookup fail, this column value will be NULL.

My problem: After this behavior above, the rest of my flow is the same. So I have two duplicated equal flows below lookup. And this is terrible for readability and maintenance.

What do I can do to resolve this situation with little performance loss? 
The data model is legacy, so change the data model is impossible.

[image]

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSIS Data Flow: Join the auxiliar flow to the main flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138319/ssis-data-flow-join-the-auxiliar-flow-to-the-main-flow)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Many people commented in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138319/ssis-data-flow-join-the-auxiliar-flow-to-the-main-flow and you simply abandoned it and asked again.

Comment: Can you create a dataset that will have a one to one lookup from your dataflow record to your final lookup? Use a merge join if so.

Comment: In production, more than 10 million rows will pass in this lookup every day, so I'm worried about using 'Union All' because performance problems.

Comment: The previous question was more general. I came from C++, so we avoid replication with modularity. In this previous question was answered that modularity is impossible in SSIS. Now I am bringing my pontual problem, already knowing that modularity is not possible. And union perharps don't resolve my problem because are more than 10 million register every day, and you said in this link: 'However, if you union after you split, it would appear there was no reason to split it in the first place'

Comment: So, I have a reason to split, but modularity is impossible, and union can bring me performance problems because the big data. And this look up will occur more than one time, in others situations, because the legacy data model. So I don't see a solution

Comment: Nick, sorry for the similar questions

Comment: I gave you an answer without the union on your last question for this problem.

Comment: I think a challenge we the experienced SSIS practitioners are having with your [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139888/ssis-is-it-possible-to-have-modularity-and-avoid-replication-inside-a-single-da) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138319/ssis-data-flow-join-the-auxiliar-flow-to-the-main-flow) is that there isn't enough detail to provide an answer. Take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on how to ask successful questions.

Comment: Specific to this question, you enrich data from A with data from B and persist to C. What happens in the case of a no match - do you store a NULL? Is it insert only to C or do you need to insert if not found in C and update if it exists? I do not understand this part of your problem statement `I have two duplicated equal flows below lookup.` Perhaps a screen capture would help us understand your current design

Comment: Keith, your answer in the previous question solves the issue that I no longer need more a join, but the principal problem of this question( code duplication ) your approach doesn't resolve, because the two paths still need repeat the same sequence after 'task4'. And are more than 10 tasks below 'task4'.

Comment: bilinkc, I store a invalid value for the business rule. I'm not allowed to show my code, but as you requested I edited the content of the post with a link to a image example. The image show the 'two duplicated equal flows below lookup' part.

Comment: Thank you for the image. Whenever I can avoid it, I do not split my output from a lookup task. Instead, I set the disposition for no match to ignore. This means that immediately after that lookup, I need to handle a possibly null retrieved column which I would do using the Derived Column transformation. I suspect this is your "DifferentStep". Something like `ISNULL(MyLookupColumn) ? -1 : MyLookupColumn` would set my value to a -1 if the lookup component didn't match - otherwise, we'd preserve the existing value.

Comment: Is this a data warehousing project? Are you attempting to handle late arriving dimensions? There are patterns and practices around this, regardless of tooling, that might help us better understand your business problem and then translate that into effective mechanisms for code implementation.

Comment: Billinkc, I used your aproach of Derived Column in one of my Packages, and the size of the flow fell in half. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, there are really three options:

1. Use UNION ALL and possibly sacrifice performance for modularity. There may in fact be *no* performance issue. You should test and see
2. If possible, implement all of this in a stored procedure. You can implement code reuse there and it will quite possibly run much faster
3. Build a [custom transformation component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects-data-flow-types/developing-a-custom-transformation-component-with-synchronous-outputs?view=sql-server-ver15) that implements those last three steps. 
   This option appeals to all programmers but may have the worst performance and in my opinion will just cause issues down the track. If you're writing reams of C# code inside SSIS then you'll eventually reach a point where it's easier to just build a standalone app.

It would be much easier to answer if you explained

- What you're really doing

  - slowly changing dimension?
  - data cleansing?
  - adding reference data?
  - spamming
- What are those three activities?

  - sending an email?
  - calling a web service?
  - calling some other API?
- What your constraints are

  - Is all of this data on one server and can you create stored procs and tables?

Comment: Thank You Nick.Dermain, I used your number 2 solution in some situations and resolved my problem. Answering your question, I am populating my Fact Table with a incremental ETL.